# Avro File Copy to Snowflake does strict data type validation before loading data into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure data Factory to load data from Azure Blob Storage to Snowflake using Avro file and using Azure Data Factory Copy Activity. The Avro File has schema inside the file ; ADF reads this schema and in copy configuration with mapping "tab" where source datatype and datasize are mapped with Snowflake Table Column data type and Size. In One of Column in Avro file is Integer and correspoding column in Snowflake table is created as Integer, but Snowflake creates this column as Numeric

When I tried to map the schema, it maps the Integer columns from Avro file to Numeric columns in Snowoflake Table column. But while running the copy task, it gives error as DataTypeMismatch.

Has anyone encountered this issue ; if yes have you used any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my environment, and it got successful.

[image]

**My sample snowflake table description:**

[image]

ADF mapping:

[image]

Make sure you have columns with the correct data type and if you are still facing the issue, you can change the data type of the column using pre-copy script. of the snowflake and below query with appropriate datatype for that column.

```
ALTER TABLE demotb3 ALTER Age SET DATA TYPE integer;
```

[image]